# How to get values in order？

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a newbie to eclipse, and I want to write an app.
Here are what i want to do:
I've created 3 strings: x y and z
each have intergers with format like ("a,b,c")
With 3 toggle button(btn1,btn2,btn3), I want to get a string "assigned" to the button and put them in order.

```
Public class MainActivity extends｛
   String a=String("2,7,3")
   String b=String("2,6,8,1")
   String c=String("6,8,9")
   String d=String()
   String e=String()

   private Button Btn1
   private Button Btn2
   private Button Btn3

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
   Btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
   Btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn3);

   Btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    d="a"+","

   }

}
}
}
```

So that's the case.....
I don't know if I make myself clear enough....but it would be awesome if you can help me out....
Thanks So Much

Comment: The above code cannot detect the order of the butoons pressed...so the strings wouldn't be in order....

Comment: It saids I don't have 20 reputation...

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: Have you actually tried typing this into Eclipse and dealing with the errors that it shows you?

Comment: yes...the above code is just a simplified one as I am not with my computer right now. The problem is how can I let Eclipse know I want to detect button press in order...

Comment: you cannot receive my email?

Comment: `String a=String("2,7,3")` should be `String a="2,7,3"`

Comment: " I want to get a string "assigned" to the button and put them in order." I don't understand what this means. Can you explain futher?

Comment: The idea is when a click(or toggle) the button, the suitable value should be send to the correct order of a long empty string'

Comment: In this case, Btn1 should send string a, Btn2 string b....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is here:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    d="a"+","
}
```

You looks like you want `String d` set to `String a` not a string a value of "a" ... the correct code is to set `String d` like this:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    d = a +","
}
```

If several buttons are pressed, then you should do the following:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    d = d + a +","
}
```

to keep them in order.

Comment: but I couldn't figure out how to arrange correct order of strings when different order of button are pressed..